# Library with identifier LabelServices is missing (perhaps it was deleted?) / Something went wrong. Please reload

Tags: google-apps-script

I have posted this on google-apps-script-issues (https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4723&can=4&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) but with no response I am getting desperate as all my sheets and scripts are breaking down. So I hope someone here might have encountered this and have some idea for me how to handle this.

Some of my exiting scripts (including some in spreadsheets) suddenly started throwing the exception 'Library with identifier LabelServices is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)'.

I tried deleting the library reference in some of the scripts that were throwing this error and re-adding it but the same error comes up. I even defined a new library with the same name and try to use it instead. Still the same error.

Most likely a related error, when trying to open project properties to these scripts I see the message 'Something went wrong. Please reload.' and the hourglass never stops. This happens at both standalone scripts and ones embeded in spreadsheets.

Please note that if I add the same library to a new script then there is no problem and the library works perfectly.

I would like to add that even if I remove the library and also any calls or references to the library the problem still persists.

Link to a script where this happens is available at https://script.google.com/d/1ptevXwu25z9Vo88zX0XOyaQk5pE5MmzwDbb-lMglNY1lzz1HBBiAeJxn/edit?usp=drive_web
You can copy it and play with it. You should get the same problem.

Appreciate any help!!!

Comment: Was it yourself who owned the LabelServices library, or was this an external library of some sort? Have you tried contacting the owner?

Comment: It is my own library.

Comment: I took a copy and stripped out all of the other libraries except LabelServices and it worked fine. Could there be some dependency issue between your libraries?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63907324

Answer (score 1):

Andrew. First of all thank you as you triggered something in my mind. I went all the way bottom up and checked each script and a library it was calling. There were obviously dependencies, however nothing that should have been a problem. a couple of libraries even though in development mode seem to cause a problem. I had to create a new version but it was not enough just to update their version in other scripts. In the calling scripts I had to remove all libraries and re-add them one by one while testing whether the project properties shows up or not. I just wish Google would have a utility to clearly highlight what was wrong because I can't figure it out though I went twice through their documentation in regard to libraries and development mode. Since I have about 30 libraries or so, not to mention spreadsheets and apps it took me nearly a whole day... Thanks again!

To all, it seems that there is a problem where sometimes libraries get out of sync (at least that's the best way I can describe it). You may need to create new versions for the libraries (even though these are in development mode. And in each problematic script remove and re-add the libraries (in at lease a couple of transactions - first remove and confirm then add - and better one at the time while checking that your project properties opens properly). This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Sad to say this answer is still relevant in 2018! I just run everything in development mode *and* create new versions for every library update. I definitely get the sense that it's all caused by libraries that are out of sync behind the scenes. I could even empty all my libraries and it would still complain about things that aren't even there in the first place.